# ActiveMQ authentication on Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I can consume and publish a message to queue without authentication in Spring App via ActiveMQ.

```
server.port=9999
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=admin
spring.activemq.packages.trust-all=true
```

I deleted user and password line. It works. But I want to take error when deleted following line or when wrong password and username.

```
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=admin
```

My authentication is true but it doesn't work.

```
<bean id="securityConstraint" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint">
    <property name="name" value="BASIC" />
    <property name="roles" value="user,admin" />
    <!-- set authenticate=false to disable login -->
    <property name="authenticate" value="true" />
</bean>
<bean id="adminSecurityConstraint" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint">
    <property name="name" value="BASIC" />
    <property name="roles" value="admin" />
     <!-- set authenticate=false to disable login -->
    <property name="authenticate" value="true" />
</bean>
```

How to get an error when Password or username is entered incorrectly? How can I open username and password for Spring boot? (I'm not asking about ActiveMQ web console authentication)
**activemq.xml :**

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core 
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">
  
<!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
      lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
      init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
</bean>
 <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

    <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
          <policyEntries>
            <policyEntry topic=">" >
                <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                     slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                     by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                     For more information, see:

                     http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                -->
              <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
              </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
            </policyEntry>
          </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>


    <!--
        The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
        JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
        the JVM. For more information, see:

        http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
    -->
    <managementContext>
        <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
    </managementContext>

    <!--
        Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
        mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
        For more information, see:

        http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
    -->
    <persistenceAdapter>
        <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>


      <!--
        The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
        use before disabling caching and/or slowing down producers. For more information, see:
        http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
      -->
      <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>

    <!--
        The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
        clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

        http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
    -->
    <transportConnectors>
        <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    </transportConnectors>

    <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
    <shutdownHooks>
        <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
    </shutdownHooks>
    
    
</broker>




<!--
    Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
    The web consoles requires by default login, you can disable this in the jetty.xml file

    Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
-->
<import resource="jetty.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The conf/jetty.xml configuration is for the webconsole. The conf/users.properties is generally where user and group information is stored for the standardized messaging protocols (JMS/STOMP/MQTT/AMQP etc) user authentication with the Apache ActiveMQ distribution.

Please sharing your conf/activemq.xml for confirmation.

Comment: Sir , i added the above.

Comment: Looks good. See this reference to adjust how you want your security to work: https://activemq.apache.org/security.html  The general setup is to use the conf/login.cfong, conf/users.properties, conf/group.properites file for user, password and group membership.